# Returning null in a method whose signature says return int?

Tags: java, null, return

```
public int pollDecrementHigherKey(int x) {
            int savedKey, savedValue;
            if (this.higherKey(x) == null) {
                return null;  // COMPILE-TIME ERROR
            }
            else if (this.get(this.higherKey(x)) > 1) {        
                savedKey = this.higherKey(x);
                savedValue = this.get(this.higherKey(x)) - 1;
                this.remove(savedKey);
                this.put(savedKey, savedValue);
                return savedKey;
            }
            else {
                savedKey = this.higherKey(x);
                this.remove(savedKey);
                return savedKey;
            }
        }
```

The method lies within a class that is an extension of TreeMap, if that makes any difference... Any ideas why I can't return null here?

Comment: Because `null` is not an `int`?

Comment: what language is it? add more tags pls. Afaik only void functions can return null, otherwise you need 0 or -1 returned. Try ´return void;` depending on the language

Comment: Russel, that would depend on the language, and in any case, please post answers as answers so we can vote in whatever direction we want.

Comment: As a workaround, you could define a contract by which you return Integer.MIN_VALUE or Integer.MAX_VALUE to mean "nothing" or "invalid value"...assuming MIN_VALUE or MAX_VALUE would otherwise never be returned.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`int` is a primitive, null is not a value that it can take on. You could change the method return type to return `java.lang.Integer` and then you can return null, and existing code that returns int will get autoboxed.

Nulls are assigned only to reference types, it means the reference doesn't point to anything. Primitives are not reference types, they are values, so they are never set to null.

Using the object wrapper java.lang.Integer as the return value means you are passing back an Object and the object reference can be null.

Comment: What language are you assuming?

Comment: @Jeppe: I'm guessing C# or Java. both of them have primitives, object wrappers and autoboxing.

Answer (score 4):

`int` is a primitive data type . It is not a reference variable which can take `null` values . You need to change the method return type to `Integer` wrapper class .

Answer (score 3):

Change your return type to java.lang.Integer . This way you can safely return null

Answer (score 0):

The type `int` is a primitive and it cannot be `null`, if you want to return `null`, mark the signature as

```java
public Integer pollDecrementHigherKey(int x) {
    x = 10;

    if (condition) {
        return x; // This is auto-boxing, x will be automatically converted to Integer
    } else if (condition2) {
        return null; // Integer inherits from Object, so it's valid to return null
    } else {
        return new Integer(x); // Create an Integer from the int and then return
    }
    
    return 5; // Also will be autoboxed and converted into Integer
}
```

Comment: `} else { ... } else {` really? :D

Answer (score -2):

Do you realy want to return null ? Something you can do, is maybe initialise savedkey with 0 value and return 0 as a null value. It can be more simple.

Comment: We don't know much from the given code, but it's possible that 0 is a legitimate return value. Your thought on returning some otherwise non-valid result to indicate failure is a good one, however.

Comment: it is not good, since java implemented exceptions for such cases.